# Verbally format a number in Python

Tags: python, formatting, nlp, language-comparisons

How do pythonistas print a number as words, like the equivalent of the Common Lisp code:

```
[3]> (format t "~r" 1e25)
nine septillion, nine hundred and ninety-nine sextillion, nine hundred and ninety-nine quintillion, seven hundred and seventy-eight quadrillion, one hundred and ninety-six trillion, three hundred and eight billion, three hundred and sixty-one million, two hundred and sixteen thousand
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

no in python core, but there is 3rd party library [num2words](https://github.com/savoirfairelinux/num2words)

```
>>> from num2words import num2words
>>> num2words(1e25)
'ten septillion, one billion, seventy-three million, seven hundred and forty-one thousand, eight hundred and twenty-four'

>>> num2words(10000000000000000000000000)
'ten septillion'
```

(note that 1e25 is not converted to integer precisely, neither in your example)

Comment: Excellent - I actually noticed that, but it's an error in how python (C?) handles the exponential expression: `int(1e25)` produces `10000000000000000905969664L` and `1*10**25` produces `10000000000000000000000000L`. Strange?

Comment: Not strange at all.  `1e25` is "make the floating-point value closest to 10^25", and `1*10**25` says "multiply 1 by the result of multiplying 10 by itself 25 times".  Fixed-width floating-point arithmetic (on a computer) is not mathematically precise, while integers in recent versions of Python are arbitrary-precision.

Comment: 1e25 is not an "exponential expression", it's a floating point literal.  And a floating point number in python cannot represent exactly 10**25 (and this shouldn't be such a big surprise given that 2**84 > 10**25 > 2**83).

Comment: interesting and informative! Based on that information, I was curious and played around a bit, and if you want accuracy you can `import decimal; d = decimal.Decimal('1e25')` and you won't get the floating-point error.

Answer (score 1):

I just started a work in Turkish, it may be helpful.

https://github.com/guneysus/humanizer-tr

It return a list of strings, and comes with easy testing functions `randomizer()` `prettizer()` and the core function `humanizer()`

It may handle very large numbers because it did not use dividing approach, but uses string segmentation and manipulation.

You can enter even number or string.

Since i did not write a number verification it can even handle a non number text
:)

```
>>> humanizer('STACK OVER FLOW')
['STA Trilyon', 'CK  Milyar', 'OVE Milyon', 'R F Bin', 'LOW']
```

Answer (score 0):

Here as a way to do it:

```
def abbreviate(x):
    abbreviations = ["", "K", "M", "B", "T", "Qd", "Qn", "Sx", "Sp", "O", "N", 
    "De", "Ud", "DD"]
    thing = "1"
    a = 0
    while len(thing) < len(str(x)) - 3:
        thing += "000"
        a += 1
    b = int(thing)
    thing = round(x / b, 2)
    return str(thing) + " " + abbreviations[a]
```

It does this:

```
>>> abbreviate(11423)
11.43 K
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question and the question is nearly nine years old!