# How to specify large integer literals in a readable way?

Tags: python, integer, number-formatting, readability

I want to specify a sequence of large integers (with many zeros) like:

```
a = [1e13, 1e14, 1e19, ...]
```

My intuition is to use scientific notation. But in python, it's a float instead of integer. Is there a easy way in python to write these integer literals without writing all the zeros, because making sure the number of zeros correct is a nightmare.

I believe I can cast the floats back to integer using `int`, but just wonder if there is a better way?

Comment: Will `a = [10 ** 13, 10 ** 14, 10 ** 19]` work for you?

Comment: There is no concise way to specify large decimal integer literals in Python ([grammar spec](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#integer-literals)). If you're lucky, CPython's peephole optimiser will replace `10**13` with `10000000000000` at compile time.

Comment: Take care with that float to integer *conversion* (nitpick: Python doesn't have "casts").  It's not always going to give you exactly the value you expect.  E.g., `int(1e23)` gives `99999999999999991611392`.

Answer (score 23):

For future viewers.

Since python 3.6 [`PEP 515`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/whatsnew/3.6.html#pep-515) would be included.

So you can do `a = 1_000_000_000_000` for better code's readability.

Answer (score 8):

Using `*` and `**`, it's not beautiful but gives you the right result.

```
print(2e10)
20000000000.0

print(2*10**10)
20000000000
```

You can also generate a whole list like this:

```
result = []
for i in range(5):
    result.append(1*10**i)


>>> result
[1, 10, 100, 1000, 10000]
```

If you really want to use the scientific notation, then

```
result = []
for n in range(5):
    result.append(int(float(f"1e{n}"))) #converting to int directly gives: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1e0'



>>> result
[1, 10, 100, 1000, 10000]
```

Comment: @user2357112 Thank you for the edit. I missed the rounding error at 1e23. An alternative, very ugly and expensive, solution would be `a = list(map(int, map(Decimal, map(str, [1e13, 1e14, 1e19, 1e23]))))`.

Answer (score 3):

In your **input**, you can specify integers with underscores.

Since python 3.10, you can also use [`pprint`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pprint.html#module-pprint) library methods, such as [`pprint.pprint`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pprint.html#pprint.pprint) and [`pprint.pformat`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pprint.html#pprint.pformat) with `underscore_numbers=True` to **output** integers with underscores. This has no effect on non-integer numbers.

Examples:

```
from pprint import pformat

nums = [1000000, 1_000_000, 1e6, 1000000.1]
for num in nums:
    print(num, pformat(num), pformat(num, underscore_numbers=True))

# 1000000 1000000 1_000_000
# 1000000 1000000 1_000_000
# 1000000.0 1000000.0 1000000.0
# 1000000.1 1000000.1 1000000.1
```

**SEE ALSO:**

[python human readable large numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3154460/967621)

Answer (score 1):

You can setup some suffixes

```
K=1000
M=K*K
G=K*M
T=K*G
P=K*T
E=K*P
print 12*P
```

or use the longer names (kilo, etc).

Answer (score 1):

You could use comma separators for thousands, as a string, then convert to an int.

```
import locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'en_US.UTF-8') 
def bigint(s):
    return locale.atoi(s)

print bigint('1,000,000,000,000')
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this, which avoids float to int conversion issues and is fairly readable in my opinion:

```
a = map(int, ['1'+'0'*13, '1'+'0'*14, '1'+'0'*19, '1'+'0'*23])
for value in a:
    print(format(value, ','))
```

Output:

```
10,000,000,000,000
100,000,000,000,000
10,000,000,000,000,000,000
100,000,000,000,000,000,000,000
```