# Convert numbers in millions and thousands to string format

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, select

I have a column in my pandas dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[3000000, 2500000, 1800000, 800000, 500000]], columns=['Market value'])
```

I want to convert the numbers in this column to a format with millions and hundred thousands, for example:

- 3000000 -> €3M
- 2500000 -> €2.5M
- 1800000 -> €1.8M
- 800000 -> €800K
- 500000 -> €500K

This is my attempt so far:

```
df['Market Value'] = np.select(condlist = [(df['Market value']/1000) >= 1000],
                               choicelist = ['€'+(df['Market value'].astype(float)/1000000).astype(int).astype(str) + 'M'],
                               default = '€'+(df['Market value'].astype(float)/1000).astype(int).astype(str) + 'K')
```

This produces the output:

- 3000000 -> €3M
- 2500000 -> €2M * **this needs to be €2.5M**
- 1800000 -> €1M * **this needs to be €1.8M**
- 800000 -> €800K
- 500000 -> €500K

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python human readable large numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3154460/python-human-readable-large-numbers)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can apply this function to the column:

```py
def format(num):
    if num > 1000000:
        if not num % 1000000:
            return f'€{num // 1000000}M'
        return f'€{round(num / 1000000, 1)}M'
    return f'€{num // 1000}K'
```

Testing:

```py
nums_list = [3000000, 2500000, 1800000, 800000, 500000]
for num in nums_list:
    print(format(num))
```

Output:

```
€3M
€2.5M
€1.8M
€800K
€500K
```

Comment: That work great, thanks! I'm now trying to add this as a column to my dataframe using the code: `for num in nums_list: df['MV'] = format(num))` but this isn't working. Do you know how to do this?

Comment: @codemachine Try this: `df['MV'] = [format(num) for num in nums_list]`

Answer (score -1):

---

- UPDATED

---

```
import math
def millify(n):
    n = float(n)
    millnames = ['',' K',' M',' B',' T']
    millidx = max(0,min(len(millnames)-1,
                        int(math.floor(0 if n == 0 else math.log10(abs(n))/3))))

    return '£' + str(n / 10**(3 * millidx)) + str(millnames[millidx])

df['Value in millions'] = df['Market value'].apply(lambda n: millify(n))
```

Output:

```
Market value    Value in millions
0   3000000         £3.0 M
1   2500000         £2.5 M
2   1800000         £1.8 M
3   800000          £800.0 K
4   500000          £500.0 K
```

For further detail you check this question [python human readable large numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3154460/python-human-readable-large-numbers)

Comment: @codemachine Try this